# IMX8Mmini firmware upgrade with fallback mechanism

Tags: yocto, u-boot, firmware, nxp-microcontroller, imx8

I need to upgrade the firmware of IMX8Mmini with fallback mechanism or secure boot. As i am new into this i am not getting proper document and any blog related to this. Can anyone help me this that how can i upgrade firmware of imx8mmini without loosing original formware in case of any unsuccessfull operation.

I also need more info on below topics which comes in my mind with the idea of firmware upgrade.

1. As i know imx8mmini image resides in sd card for running imx8mmini
   processor so do i need to create third partition for containing new
   firmware image apart from root and boot.
2. As i upgrade firmware then what all things would change in order to upgrade firmware(dtb,tmp and rootfs files). Or is there any machanism so i can upgrade
   firmware without creating extra partition.

   I need help on above topic and firmware upgrade mainly. Please share
   your knowledge or document related to this. It would be highly
   appreaciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: IMHO, this question is too broad for a concrete answer. Because you tagged with Yocto, I recommend reading https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/System_Update for A/B Firmware updates.